# Illegal instruction: 4 "${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint"

Tags: yaml, swiftlint

When updating SwiftLint 0.16.1 to SwiftLint 0.18.1, I get:

> /Users/coeur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-7-eloayqptodupvfhbyegtkncnhcpu/Build/Intermediates/MyApp-7.build/UAT-iphonesimulator/MyApp-7-Debug.build/Script-379156A71D62F5C100574D04.sh: line 2: 30296 Illegal instruction: 4 "${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint"
>   Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 132

DerivedData is clean.
Using Xcode 8.3.1, CocoaPods 1.2.1, Swift 3.1.

My **.swiftlint.yml**:

```
# Find all the available rules by running:
# swiftlint rules

excluded:
- Carthage
- Pods

disabled_rules:
  - todo
  - line_length

opt_in_rules:
  - empty_count

trailing_whitespace:
 ignores_empty_lines: true
 ignores_comments: true
large_tuple: warning: 3
type_name: max_length: warning: 42
variable_name: min_length: warning: 1
```

Comment: @Makyen Thank you for the script. Judging if a question is close-worthy or delete worthy often requires more time than I can afford. I still flag and vote when I can evaluate it with no doubt. Currently, 1,954 votes cast and 163 post flags. Note that I made [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/653093) not too long ago, and once I finish fixing a few title typo, I'll tacle the hundreds of duplicates. Just, I'm acting at the level of my abilities, so forgive me for not closing/downvoting everything right away.

Comment: @Makyen can you add a link to the script on your own profile?

Comment: Yes, but I'd have to create a profile, which I've generally avoided, but should do so. Let me think about what I want to have there (other than that). Here's the link again if you need it: [Roomba Forecaster](http://stackapps.com/questions/7239/roomba-forecaster-when-will-the-question-be-roombaed-if-it-wont-why). It's also indirectly available as the only question I've posted on [stackapps.se], which can be gotten to (indirectly) through my network profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftLint 0.18.x introduce a breaking change. They replace **YamlSwift** with **Yams**. Yams interprets YAML more strictly than YamlSwift, so if your **.swiftlint.yml** configurations previously worked with SwiftLint but didn't fully conform to the [YAML 1.2 standard](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), you'll need to fix those validation errors.

In your (my) case, each mapping entry (denoted with a colon `:`) needs to be on its own line:

```
large_tuple:
 warning: 3
type_name:
 max_length:
  warning: 42
variable_name:
 min_length:
  warning: 1
```

Note that a pull request was made to avoid crashing SwiftLint with this issue in the future: https://github.com/jpsim/Yams/pull/37